# alias can't be opened

Tags: finder, alias

This is about a MacBook running on 10.10.5 whose disk has recently been repaired (to try to solve the present issue) using Disk Utility. I created an alias as follows:

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ ls -ld
drwx------+ 13 erwann  staff  442 Jul 14 12:41 .
$ touch foo.bar
$ mkdir baz
$ ln -s foo.bar baz   
$ ls -l baz
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 erwann  staff  7 Jul 15 11:02 foo.bar -> foo.bar
```

Next, I use Finder to 'Show [the] original' associated with the alias created in 'baz'. I get:

> The alias “foo.bar” can’t be opened because the original item can’t be found.

Any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to simply right click and select Make Alias? then move it where you want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link needs an absolute path.

```
ln -s foo.bar baz
```

will create an alias in `baz` pointing to the file `foo.bar`. But the file `baz/foo.bar` does not exist, hence the error you received.

You want:

```
ln -s ~/Desktop/foo.bar baz
```

which will create an alias in the `baz` directory pointing to `~/Desktop/foo.bar`.